# I have created an call back API to receive the JSON data but its not working

Tags: php, json

I have created a call back **API** to receive the **JSON** data after hitting my server. But somehow its not working as expected

This the response which i have to receive in my **API**

`{"ERROR":0,"STATUS":1,"ORDERID":753093,"OPTRANSID":"2107938600"}`

I have written the **php** file for this **rcstatus.php**

```
$url = 'http://softwarecompany.club/pks/recharge/b2b/rcstatus.php?status='.$_GET['status'].'&Orderid='.$_GET['Orderid'].'&Optransid='.$_GET['Optransid'];

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 30000);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo $data;
$json = json_decode($url,true);
$json['STATUS'];
```

Please help me to achieve this. I have never worked with JSON data before. So please help me to achieve it. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Is it typo in question? you decode $url, not $data

Comment: Can you help me how to fix this problem

Comment: You can print response by `print_r($json);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to replace:

```
$json = json_decode($url,true);
```

with

```
$json = json_decode($data,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace $url to $data in last when you get the response like this.

```
$url = 'http://softwarecompany.club/pks/recharge/b2b/rcstatus.php?status='.$_GET['status'].'&Orderid='.$_GET['Orderid'].'&Optransid='.$_GET['Optransid'];

$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS, 30000);
$data = curl_exec($ch); // This is Your Response 
$json = json_decode($data,true);
$json['STATUS'];
```